# Show map with latitude longitude isnt working

Tags: php, google-maps

I have used this code to show map using latitude and longitude in my laravel project.

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=[12],[56]
```

But map isnt appearing.
latitude and longitude are text field saved in database. Is this because of that? How can I fix this? TIA

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=[12,56]
```

So edit your code to

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=[{{$setting->latitude}},{{$setting->longitude}}]
```

and you should be fine